# Make a child div visible on click

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Edit my code to make it work please.

Edited for latest version.

Here is what I have:

```
<body>
<!-- visibility toggle -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility()
    {
       if(document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id+'menu').style.display=='block'){
            document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id+'menu').style.display='none';
        }
        else{ 
            document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id+'menu').style.display='block';
        }
    };
//-->
</script>
```

Here are my divs (edited to show exactly what I have)

```
<ul class="lyrics"><h3>ALL LYRICS</h3>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
        <li ><a id="links" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility();"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <div id="linksmenu"><?php the_content();?></div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>
</ul>
```

Here is what happens:
Regardless which link I click on, only the text associated with the very last "the_content" displays.

Here is what I need:
Initially all the "child" divs are not visible.
When I click on "Title 1" link, the "Child text 1" will become visible.
When I click on "Title 2" link, the "Child text 2" will become visible and the "Child text 1" will become not visible.

This is going to be in a WordPress blog so the number of Title divs will change. There will always be only one child.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are you calling the `toggle_visibility` function? i.e., where is your event handler?

Comment: We need to see the output of the PHP functions to determine the problem.

Comment: do you want us to write and debug code for you or do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason why your first `div` is toggled no matter where you click, is because you use the hard-coded id `foo`. Pass `this` to `toggle_visibility` instead of the literal `'foo'` and inside `toggle_visibility` function find the div that you want to toggle (this is going to be the first child of the passed parameter).

Answer (score 0):

It is doing this because you are calling `the_content()` twice. I am assuming your file looks like:

```
<?php get_header();
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<ul> 
<li class="main"><a href="#" title="Title 1"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   <div class="child"><?php the_content(); ?></div> </li> 
<li class="main"><a href="#" title="Title 2"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   <div class="child"><?php the_content(); ?></div> </li>  <ul> 
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You need to have two loops, but I can't supply detail without seeing more code. Read about [multiple loops](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added addition information to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Throw the parameter away and build the id you want to set visible/invisible using the id of the element which triggers the event.

```
 function toggle_visibility()
        {
            if(document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id+'menu').style.display=='block'){
                document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id+'menu').style.display='none';
            }
            else{ 
                document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id+'menu').style.display='block';
            }
        };
```

And as long as the thing you want to show always has a id+'menu' or whatever, you can show it with the function. (notice that the parent has id `links` and the child has  id `linksmenu` )

```
<ul class="lyrics"><h3>ALL LYRICS</h3>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
    <li ><a id="links" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility();"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      <div id="linksmenu"><?php the_content();?></div>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: The above code only displays the very last "linksmenu" text regardless which link is clicked. For example: I have Link 1, Link 2 and if I click Link 1 I get Link 1 text, if I click Link 2 I get Link 1 text.

Comment: and do you have link1menu, link2menu and so on?